# Relationship between simple group and character table

Tags: representation-theory

Prove that a group $G$ is not simple iff $\chi (g)=\chi (1)$ for some nontrivial character $\chi$ and some $g\not= 1$.

I have no idea how to do this, please help, thanks.

Comment: You need to find a non-trivial normal subgroup, and you have so little information there aren't many options. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Here's a hint: If $G$ is not simple, then there is a surjective homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ to some group $H \neq 1$ and $ker\ f \neq \{1\}$. Pick a nontrivial character $\psi$ of $H$ and put $\varphi := \psi \circ f$. Check that $\varphi$ is a nontrivial character of $G$. Then, pick a $g \in\ ker\ f$ with $g \neq 1$. Check that $\varphi(g) = \varphi(1).$

Answer (score 1):

Jflipp actually proved that if $G$ is not simple then there are such $\chi$ and $g$.

Opposite seems a bit harder for me. My prove even is not algebraic. I will assume field to be $\mathbb{C}$. If you would like, I can provide more details (in case if it is not $\mathbb{C}$ ).
Consider a representation $(V, \rho)$. All eigenvalue of $\rho (g)$ are root of union. So their norm is one. Sum of this eigenvalue is $ \dim(V)$ (notice that $\dim V$ is number of summands). So they are equal to 1.